# Can I limit the number of inotify watches available to a process or cgroup?

Tags: linux, limit, inotify

I am consistently running out of inotify resources, leading to errors along the lines of:

```
# tail -f /some/files
tail: inotify resources exhausted
tail: inotify cannot be used, reverting to polling
```

This eventually happens even if I grow the value of `fs.inotify.max_user_watches`.  I suspect a locally installed Java application is consuming the resources, but I don't have the option of either fixing it or removing it.

Is there a way to set a limit on the number of inotify watches that can be consumed by a process?